# Persisting the font settings for gitk

Tags: git, gitk

You may change the font settings of a gitk window by making changes in Edit->Preferences. But these settings are reflected only for that session of gitk.

How can I persist the font settings for all further sessions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should see, when you quit gitk, a setting file created/updated in:

```
%HOMEPATH%\.config/git/gitk
```

It will include a line like:

```
set mainfont {{Calibri Light} 9}
```

Those settings will persists across sessions.